# Reflection not restricted even if it's not in grant set

Tags: c#, .net, security, .net-4.0, sandbox

I'm currently trying to create a very very simple *sandbox*.

Some class *A* has a method *Execute* which is invoked in another `AppDomain` than the caller.

Problem is I've execution permission only and reflection is possible anyway.

This is the code sample:

```
[Serializable]
public class A : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        typeof(A).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null); // Fine - Why?
        typeof(B).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null); // Fine - Why?
    }
}

public class B
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PermissionSet set = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);

        SecurityPermission security = new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution);
        set.AddPermission(security);

        Evidence evidence = new Evidence();
        AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        setup.ApplicationBase = "C:";

        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain
        (
            "hello",
            evidence,
            setup,
            set
        );

        A a = (A)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(A).FullName);
        a.Execute();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

**Great!** Finally I did it.

Thanks to your advices I've revised my code and I'd like to share it with you, since I had a hard time understanding how to *don't use CAS but use same kind of permissions in the new .NET 4.x and above security model, and the way of sandboxing using an `AppDomain`*. That's it:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.Policy;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [Serializable]
    public class A : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
        B b = new B();

        // BOMB! ERROR! Security demand: reflection forbidden!
        b.GetType()
                .GetMethod("ExecuteInB", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                    .Invoke(b, null);
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        private void ExecuteInB()
        {

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PermissionSet set = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);

            SecurityPermission security = new SecurityPermission(PermissionState.None);
            security.Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution;
            set.AddPermission(security);

            Evidence evidence = new Evidence();
            AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
            setup.ApplicationBase = "C:";

            AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain
            (
                "hola",
                evidence,
                setup,
                set
            );

            A a = (A)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("ConsoleApplication1", "ConsoleApplication1.A");
            a.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reflection permission is demanded when invoking an *inaccessible* member. `A` and `B` are public types with public constructors, and so are accessible. You could invoke those constructors *without* reflection, so there is no demand when you attempt to do so *with* reflection.

Moreover, using reflection for *discovery* is always legal; you can interrogate an object and ask it for a list of its private members, even without reflection permission being granted. It is only when you attempt to cause an *invocation* of the private member that the permission is demanded.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermission.aspx): `ReflectionPermission` controls access to *non-public* types and members through the System.Reflection APIs. Without `ReflectionPermission`, code can use reflection to access only the public members of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your code on .net 3.5? .NET 4 has a new
security model where the grant sets do no longer affect the sansbox. I was seriously bitten by this when I wanted to test code intended to run in medium trust contexts on a full trust .net process.

A possible solution is to force the CLR to use the legacy security model and then explicitly deny ReflectionPermission in the new AppDomain.

Sorry for the partial answer, I'm on mobile right now but will check back tomorrow. Hope this gets you started.

Comment: On top of that, I think you cant deny public reflection, only private reflection is affected.

Comment: No, I didn't in 3.5. I know about this security change, but I don't find how to achieve this result w/o using permissions.

Comment: Neither did I, so I did use [NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409253.aspx). Eric is right wrt to the effect of ReflectionPermission. I would love to present you a better solution than this, but unfortunately I have none. Keep us posted when you find something new.

Comment: Sadly I won't be able to dig more on this until this evening (GMT+1). But as far as I know, Microsoft has never said permissions are obsolete. _CAS_ is obsolete, but anyway, this AppDomain.CreateDomain overload is the recommended now for creating sandboxes in .NET 4 and above (now I'm @ work, I can't use my time to look for the MSDN article, but I'm absolutely sure about this). The point is Microsoft has declared _CAS_ obsolete and they talk a lot about a "new security model" but there's few documentation about "how to use this new model" [...]

Comment: [...] and they talk about using OS-level restrictions with Windows Restriction Policies, but I don't find how to implement Restriction Policies in order to restrict code-level things...

Comment: Check my answer and its update, it worked! And without legacy compatibility. This is the right way of doing it in .NET 4.x

Comment: So is security.Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution; all youve changed? Would be really great to see this work!

Comment: No! I didn't need to change anything: it was working fine! Problem was I thought member discovery was forbidden too if there's no ReflectionPermission _unrestricted_, but check my update in my own question, the second part, where I say "error!", I'm invoking a private method. This invocation fails, because there's no reflection permission.